# Can one Azure Mobile Service push notifications to Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 apps?

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have a Windows 8 app in the store that uses Azure Mobile Services to send push notifications. I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 version of the app now but I can't seem to get the Mobile service to push notifications to both platforms. [This page suggests that it's possible](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/multiple-clients-single-service/).

When sending a push to Windows Phone I get this error "The cloud service is not authorized to send a notification to this URI even though they are authenticated."

If I remove the Package SID from the push settings of the Mobile service then pushing to Phone works but to the Windows 8 app doesn't.

Is this a scenario that's supported? Is there any sample demonstrating it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to send notifications to both a Windows Store and WP8 apps that use the same backend Mobile Service. Can you share the code that you are using to send out the notifications to both platforms? The error message you are getting looks like the error message from the *Windows* Notification Service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx - see the Response Codes section), not the Microsoft Push (Phone) Notification Service.

Also, make sure that you have associated your app with the Store. Someone posted in the Azure Mobile Services forum with the same error message and this was the cause. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/05b0ea71-f498-46bc-b6c0-16491b14ea99/error-in-push-notifications?forum=azuremobile

Note that the Package SID and Client Secret that you specify in the Azure portal (on the Push tab) only apply to Windows Store apps - Mobile Services does not currently support authenticated notifications for WP8.

Comment: Yep, I was still trying to send a raw notification to the phone using wns rather than mpns. Thanks!